# CKEditor in XPages: how to prevent it from adding http to links?

Tags: ckeditor, xpages

I want to insert relative links in CKEditor, but the dialog keeps adding "http://" to the code it inserts.  I am using the default link button that comes with CKEditor with the "full" toolobar configuration.

Is there a way to prevent that through simple configuration or I need to edit some JS file?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked recently, but when I looked at the CKEditor files in, I think, 8.5.2 there was specific coding in the JavaScript to throw an error if a link was prefixed with anything other than "http://", "https://" and one other, possibly "ftp://". I can't remember the specifics and I think I was looking to try to add "notes://" links at the time.